# WSO2ESB. Is there a way to set request header on ?tryit tool

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created proxy service on WSO2ESB 4.9.0 and want to test it with **?tryit** tool. It has editor where i can type request body, but also i need to set request header (Cookie, for example). Can i do this with **?tryit** service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can set only the body in the tryit tool. I sugget you to use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) for serious web service development / testing.